# VS Code cursor bug in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal

Cursor repeating and remaining in the Integrated Terminal in VS Code

[image: screenshot of VS Code]

I encountered this bug in my terminal while doing Python tutorial so downloaded and reinstalled the same version (latest version of VS Code) but the problem persists. I looked about for some answers but only found [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial/) which is not related.

Anyway, I reinstalled the software only to find the bug was still present. The code runs but the cursor is an obstruction. From time to time I may type in the wrong execution so it's a bit of a bother.

Comment: What software did you reinstall exactly? Are you referring to the reinstall of VSCode you already mentioned? Cause you don't need to repeat yourself :)

Comment: What OS are you using? macOS? What shell is VSCode launching? Bash? How is the prompt (PS1) configured?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I edited your question to improve some things.

Comment: This might be an encoding problem. Obviously the shell is executing the command properly, but it seems like the terminal isn't rendering it properly. I'm not sure how you'd troubleshoot that, but you could start by checking the output of the shell command `locale charmap` and check the value of the VSCode setting `terminal.integrated.detectLocale`. Either way, it doesn't seem to be related to Python.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input @wjandrea. The terminal.integrated.detectLocale is set to auto. The encoding is UTF-8 but I do not understand how that has an impact. Another program must be corrupting the VS Code Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned off GPU acceleration in the Terminal of VS Code. That has seemed to resolve the matter; No longer cursor trails.

Settings > Type 'Render' > Go to

Terminal › Integrated: Gpu Acceleration.

Setting controls whether the terminal will leverage the GPU to do its rendering.

Switch 'off' in dropdown menu

Comment: Thank you. I had some other strange behaviour with the cursor in the vs code terminal where holding the arrow key to move the cursor in a long command would cause issues, disabling GPU acceleration also fixed my issue.